# Deseo actualizar un TextView de un Fragment cuando elimino una fila de un RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragment

> Tengo un sumador en un TextView de todos los elementos de un
>   RecyclerView. Este es mi código en el Adapter:

```
public class ViewHolderProductos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener { TextView etiNombre, etiCantidad, etiSubtotal, etiPrecio; Button btnEliminar; Button btnAumentar; Button btnDisminuir; TextView totalProductoPedido; Context context; MainActivity m; RequestQueue requestQueue; CatalogoProductosFragment vistacatalogo;

    public ViewHolderProductos(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context = itemView.getContext();
        m = new MainActivity();
        etiNombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreProductoPedido);
        etiPrecio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.precioProductoPedido);
        etiCantidad = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cantidadProductoPedido);
        etiSubtotal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtotalProductoPedido);
        btnAumentar = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAumentarCantidadDetallePedido);
        btnDisminuir = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDisminuirCantidadDetallePedido);
        btnEliminar = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnEliminarDetallePedido);
        vistacatalogo = new CatalogoProductosFragment();
    }

    void setOnClickListeners() {
        btnEliminar.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnDisminuir.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAumentar.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setearTotal() {
        Float total = 0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < listaProductos.size(); i++) {
            total += listaProductos.get(i).getSubtotal();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int position = getAdapterPosition();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnEliminarDetallePedido:
                **//AQUÍ AGREGO LA LÓGICA PARA ELIMINAR**
                if(m.isOnlineNet()) {
                    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
                    String URL_ELIMINARDP = Utilidades.WEB_SERVICE + "?accion=ELIMINAR_DETALLE_PEDIDO";
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_ELIMINARDP,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    //BASTANTE ÚTIL PARA VER ERRORES
                                    Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+response+"]");
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject rptaJson = new JSONObject(response);
                                        String respuesta = rptaJson.getString("1");
                                        if(respuesta.equals("1")) {
                                            listaProductos.remove(position);
                                            notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            setearTotal();
                                        } else if(respuesta.equals("2")) {
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+error+"]");
                        }
                    }){
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            parametros.put("id_detalle", listaProductos.get(position).getId()+"");
                            return parametros;
                        }
                    };
                    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
                    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                }
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Como vemos, cada vez que doy click a un botón en un Item de un RecyclerView, elimino la fila y también lo hago en la base de datos, luego en la función setearTotal() obtengo el nuevo total y ese dato deseo enviarlo al Fragmente para actualizar el EditText.

Ejemplo:

**EN EL RecyclerView**

- ITEM 1: [Button btnEliminar] Cantidad = 5
- ITEM 2: [Button btnEliminar] Cantidad = 10

**EN EL Fragment**

[TextView Total] = 15

*Cuando doy click en btnEliminar del ITEM 1, deseo actualizar el TextView a 10
¿Cómo podría hacerlo, muchas gracias de antemano?*

Answer (score 0):

Debes eliminar notifyDataSetChanged(); ya que con el notifyItemRemoved(position);
Estas Notificando a los observadores registrados que el elemento ubicado en esa position se ha eliminado del conjunto de datos.

Comment: Hola Juan, mi problema es que deseo obtener un dato en el Adapter y pasarlo a una vista. Tengo un RecyclerView con varios registros, supongamos que tengo Fila 1 = 20, Fila 2 = 30, Fila 3 = 40 y Fila 4 = 50. En otra parte de la vista tengo un TextView en donde aparece la suma total, es decir 20 + 30 + 40 + 50 = 140. Cuando yo elimino una fila obtengo la nueva suma, pero ese dato no puedo pasarlo a la vista. No puedo actualizar el TextView de la vista

Comment: Vale entiendo entonces has esto en tu adapter

Answer (score 0):

Podrias pasar tu TextView total como parametro en el contructor de tu adapter y en tu metodo de setearTotal() asignarle el valor, algo asi:

```
public class ViewHolderProductos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    ...
    ...
    TextView txtTotal;

    public ViewHolderProductos(params, params, ..., TextView txtView) {
        ...
        ...
        this.txtTotal = txtView;
    }

    private void setearTotal() {
        Float total = 0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < listaProductos.size(); i++) {
            total += listaProductos.get(i).getSubtotal();
        }
        txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asi puede tener acción de tu adapter en tu activity

```
private ViewHolderProductosAdapter.CustomOnItemProductoClickListener listener;

public interface CustomOnItemProductoClickListener {
    void onClickListener(View view, int id_detalle);
}

class ActivityExample implements CustomOnItemProductoClickListener {

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v, int id_detalle) {
        la acción que quieras hacer
    }
}
```